# Unable to construct the right absolute path using path module

Tags: node.js, path, mern

The folder structure of my MERN app is as follows:

[image]

As you can see, inside the `hamburger` directory, there are two directories: `client` and `server`.

Inside `index.js`, which is inside the `server` directory, I am constructing an absolute path to `index.html`, which is inside the `client\build` directory. See the highlighted section below:

[image]

**hamburger/server/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const colors = require("colors");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const {
  notFound,
  globalErrorHandler,
} = require("./middleware/errorMiddleware");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const downloadRoutes = require("./routes/downloadRoutes");

dotenv.config();

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/download", downloadRoutes);

// Routing logic in production

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.use(notFound);
app.use(globalErrorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold);
});
```

**THE PROBLEM**
Currently, the absolute path resolves to `server\client\build\index.html`, which is wrong, because the `client` directory is not inside the `server` directory; it is inside the `hamburger` directory.

**WHAT DO I WANT?**
What is the change that I need to make inside `path.resolve()` so that I get the right absolute path to `index.html`, which is inside the `client\build` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `../` to move 1 directory up where your client folder is present to build correct path.

```
path.resolve(__dirname, "../client", "build", "index.html")
```

use [`path.join`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths)

```
path.join(__dirname, '../', 'client', 'build', 'index.html')
```

or

```
path.join(__dirname, '../client', 'build', 'index.html')
```

or

```
path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html')
```

Comment: None of the solution works. I guess I will have to change the folder structure.

Comment: @HKS did you try to`console.log` what path are you getting ?

Comment: Tried again. `path.resolve(__dirname, "../client", "build", "index.html")` worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As your `index.js` is inside the `server` folder the absolute path will always be like `server\client\build\index.html`.

To address your problem either you've to change the folder structure or you've to manually construct the path.